# The CKEditor dialogDefinition event isn't firing when I right click a table and choose Table Properties

Tags: dialog, ckeditor

Set up a debugger in a dialogDefinition event callback, then right click a table and choose Table Properties. The event isn't firing for me. It's only firing when I click the button.

Comment: WFM. It is called when I open dialog from context menu and when I open it from toolbar.

Comment: I'm running 4.4.0. What about you?

Comment: I was checking latest master. But I know now where's the confusion. I was only checking whether event is fired and you were perhaps waiting for specific dialog name (`table` or `tableProperties`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for `event.data.name` to be equal to `"table"` but it comes through as `"tableProperties"` for the context menu option.

Comment: One dialog is for creating a new table and the other to edit existing tables.